# Instanciar Fragments apenas uma vez com navigationBotton

Tags: android, android-fragment

Galera boa noite, 
preciso muito de uma força, estou implementando um navigation Bottom para navegar por fragments, porém em uma das fragments vai existir um contador e quando navego pelas telas o contador reinicia.

existe uma forma de salvar o status da fragment para que o contador permaneça?

Desde ja agradeço

```
  mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_item1:
                            mTitle_Toolbar.setText(getString(R.string.toobar_call_activity));
                            //mToolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_reorder_white_24dp);
                            //selectedFragment = CalledFragment.newInstance();
                            fragmentManager(CalledFragment.newInstance(),getString(R.string.toobar_call_activity) );
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item2:
                            mTitle_Toolbar.setText(getString(R.string.toobar_project_activity));
                            //mToolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_assignment_turned_in_white_24dp);
                            selectedFragment = ProjectsFragment.newInstance();
                            fragmentManager(Profilefragment.newInstance(),getString(R.string.toobar_project_activity) );
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item3:
                            mTitle_Toolbar.setText(getString(R.string.toobar_profile_activity));
                            //mToolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_account_box_white_24dp);
                            //selectedFragment = Profilefragment.newInstance();
                            fragmentManager(Profilefragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.toobar_profile_activity));
                            break;
                    }
                    //fragmentManager(selectedFragment);
                    return true;
                }
            });
    mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.action_item1);
}



public void fragmentManager(Fragment mFragment, String tag){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, mFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: Uma alternativa é manter o contador fora do fragmento.

Comment: eu pensei nisso, mas eu não sei como atualizaria na tela o cronometro

Comment: Ajudaria se vc explicasse o intuito do contador e mostrasse como ele é inicializado.